# Can you 'export' output results in python?

Tags: python, import

Let's say I compute five lists of random integers and save it to a variable `rands` like this:

```
rands=[]
for _ in range(5):
    rands.append([random.randint(0,10) for _ in range(5)])
```

Then I print it:

```
[[9, 1, 1, 6, 10], [4, 7, 8, 7, 6], [10, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 2, 6, 7], [9, 1, 3, 6, 3]]
```

Then I do it again:

```
rands2=[]
for _ in range(5):
    rands2.append([random.randint(0,10) for _ in range(5)])
```

and also print it:

```
[[4, 8, 4, 8, 7], [5, 3, 5, 8, 3], [2, 0, 6, 3, 0], [1, 3, 2, 2, 6], [9, 10, 3, 10, 0]]
```

Can I 'export' these two lists to a `test.py` file so I can import them afterwards? Like this:

```
rands=[[9, 1, 1, 6, 10], [4, 7, 8, 7, 6], [10, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 2, 6, 7], [9, 1, 3, 6, 3]]
rands2=[[4, 8, 4, 8, 7], [5, 3, 5, 8, 3], [2, 0, 6, 3, 0], [1, 3, 2, 2, 6], [9, 10, 3, 10, 0]]
```

so that I can do `from test import rands, rands2` when I need these variables?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose you can use the Pickle module.

1. In your original python file:

```py
import pickle

my_object = [1, 2, 3, 4]

with open('filename', 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(my_object, file)
```

2. Read this binary from the new file (`test.py`) to get the object:

```py
import pickle

with open('filename', 'rb') as file:
    my_object = pickle.load(file)
```

Then you will be able to import this object with: `from test import my_object`

Answer (score 2):

You can make a `test.py` which includes `rands` and `rands2` like you wrote, then call `from test import rands, rands2` to use those variables in another python program in the same directory as `test.py`. If you want to import `test.py` from elsewhere, it has to be in [the module search path](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path).

Further reading:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

To `export` variables, they have to be defined in a python script. It's generally a bad idea to use Python to write more Python. What you might like to do is export those variables to a JSON file, then read them from that JSON file.

Further reading on JSON export and import:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

JSON is a special format for storing data that makes it easy to load/unload for a computer. You might store `rands` and `rands2` in a Python dict, then export that dictionary to a JSON file.

Example:

```
rands=[[9, 1, 1, 6, 10], [4, 7, 8, 7, 6], [10, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 2, 6, 7], [9, 1, 3, 6, 3]]
rands2=[[4, 8, 4, 8, 7], [5, 3, 5, 8, 3], [2, 0, 6, 3, 0], [1, 3, 2, 2, 6], [9, 10, 3, 10, 0]]



import json

# Store the data
with open('test.json', 'w+') as fout:
    json.dump({'rands':rands, 'rands2':rands2}, fout)

# Retrieve the data
with open('test.json') as fin:
    test = json.load(fin)
    rands = test['rands']
    rands2 = test['rands2']
```

Comment: the json.load('test.json') gives an error in your example:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: Sorry! My bug. Fixed it.